# How to test if data follows a half-normal distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, shapiro-wilk-test

There are many ways to test if the data comes from normal distribution. [**like this post**](https://towardsdatascience.com/6-ways-to-test-for-a-normal-distribution-which-one-to-use-9dcf47d8fa93)

But **the question is** how to test if the data follows **half-normal** distribution?

I know Ks-test, but as the post above states: "The KS test is well-known but it **has not much power**. It can be used for other distribution than the normal."

So is there a **more powerful way**?(I considered copy the data and set them negative to test for full normal distribution, but this seems a little problematic)

Comment: Why bother with a test? Use a smoother, then superimpose the density curve you believe the distribution follows. A picture is worth a thousand tests.

Comment: To follow up on @AdamO's suggestion, I want to suggest to you the notion that model selection is a *relative* procedure, not an absolute one.  We have no way of knowing whether data "truly" follow a given distribution.  What we really care about is whether the data follow a distribution close enough for a given application.  A null hypothesis test cannot possibly answer this for you; in fact, null hypothesis testing tells us very little, on the whole.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I totally understands this, and my density curve clearly shows a half-normal dis. But the point is I am curious that is there a general method to test? Because for normal dis, we have Shapiro Wilk.

Comment: The response to 'How do i get more power?'  is ... *against which kinds of alternatives*?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: I am no statistician**

However, since I am facing the same problem, let me tell you how I am currently trying to tackle it. My method does not verify that data is distributed half-normally, but only flags cases where this is most likely not the case. Note, however, that my method might well be fundamentally flawed.

## Working Principle

The nice thing about a half-normal distribution is, that it is determined by only *one parameter*, the standard-deviation of the underlying normal $\sigma_N$. Source [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution)] gives equations to relate the mean $\mu_H$, standard deviation $\sigma_H$, quantiles etc. of the *half-normal* to the $\sigma_N$. Even more, it gives closed-form equations to obtain $\sigma_N$, given $\mu_H$ or $\sigma_H$.
For example we see that
$$
\sigma_N = \mu_H\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.
$$
This relationship allows us to predict *all further datapoints of the distribution* just from $\mu_H$.
This is something we can leverage: For example, we can use it to predict how likely it is to e.g. obtain the measured standard-deviation $\sigma_H$ given the mean $\sigma_N$.

## Methods

### Method 1: Variance Test (computational)

Since I was not able to find an analytic expression for the distribution of sample-variances of a half-normal distribution (cf. [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538376/distribution-of-sample-variances-for-half-normal-distributions)), I tried to do solve it using a small Python script:

```py
import numpy as np
def calc_p_var(mean_h: float, n: int, std_h: float, N: int = 100000) -> float:
        """
        Estimates the probability to measure the standard-deviation std_h given
        half-normal mean mean_h and sample_size n.
        """
        #simulate possible outcomes for standard deviations given the mean
        std_n = mean_h*np.sqrt(np.pi / 2)
        X = np.abs(std_n * np.random.randn(N, n))
        stds_exp = np.std(X, axis=1)
        values, bins = np.histogram(stds_exp, bins=101)
        values = values/N
        #determine p
        return np.sum(values[bins[1:] <= std_h])
```

### Method 2: $L_2$-Test (analytical)

Based on [this idea](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538376/distribution-of-sample-variances-for-half-normal-distributions#comment988092_538376) of Xi'an, we can also use the $L_2$ norm, $\Vert X\Vert_2^2:=\sum_i X_i^2$ as a test statistic. The reasoning behind this is as follows:
If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_N)^2$ and we define $Y:=\vert X\vert$, then $\Vert X \Vert_2^2 \sim \Vert Y \Vert_2^2$.
This implies that
$$
\frac{\Vert Y \Vert_2^2}{\sigma_N^2} = \frac{\Vert X \Vert_2^2}{\sigma_N^2} \sim \chi^2_n
$$
([2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538376/distribution-of-sample-variances-for-half-normal-distributions#comment988166_538376), [3](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/26/26.3)).
This means that we found an analytic expression for the distribution of $\Vert Y \Vert_2^2/\sigma_N^2$ which we can use as a test statistic. In more detail we have that
$$
\frac{2\Vert Y \Vert_2^2}{\mu_H^2\pi} \sim \chi^2_n.
$$

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

def calc_p_l2(Y: np.ndarray) -> float:
    """
    Estimates the probability that a distribution does not originate from a half-normal distribution.
    """
    var_n = np.mean(Y)**2 * np.pi / 2
    n = len(Y)
    chi = np.sum(Y.flatten()**2) / var_n
    return scipy.stats.chi2.cdf(chi, n)
```

**I would be really glad if I could some qualified feedback on this method.**